# How can I declare variable sequentially

Tags: java, variables

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ListNode node1 = new ListNode(4);
    ListNode node2 = new ListNode(5);
    ListNode node3 = new ListNode(2);
    ListNode node4 = new ListNode(21);
    ListNode node5 = new ListNode(43);
    ListNode node6 = new ListNode(52);
    ListNode node7 = new ListNode(12);
   }
```

I want to declare variables sequentially using 'for' or 'while' syntax in JAVA.

In C, I know that there is a way of declaring variables sequentially using MACRO

But, In java, How can I do this?

Comment: Declare variables sequentially in loop????

Comment: _declare_ or _define_? What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `array of Objects` like this by using a `for loop`:

```
ListNode[] node = new ListNode[7];
for(int i = 0; i<7; i++) {
    //scan a value you want to pass
    node[i] = new ListNode(valueyouwanttopass);
}
```

or by using a `while loop` as shown below:

```
ListNode[] node = new ListNode[7];
int i = 0;
while(i<7) {
    //scan a value you want to pass
    node[i] = new ListNode(valueyouwanttopass);
    i++;
}
```